# tcl svg gradient transformation not working - gradient silently ignored

Tags: image, svg, tcl, tk-toolkit, tksvg

I'm using [tksvg 0.7.4](https://pypi.org/project/tksvg/) and noticed that the gradient transformation isn't working.
Despite some features are not supported (yet) by [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl), this feature is explicitly mentioned as supported in [TIP 507](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/507.md) and as far as I know this package is just about to be included in tk 8.7.

I use the following data:

```html
<svg width="120" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15"
      width="100" height="100" fill="url(#Gradient1)"/>
  <rect
    x="10"
    y="120"
    rx="15"
    ry="15"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    fill="url(#Gradient2)" />
</svg>
```

and tried unsuccessfully to alternate the data with the following line in the body and included it in the header as I found elsewhere in a tutorial.

```
<gradientTransform="rotate(90)" \>
```

While the TIP is marked as `done` I think it should work already. I'm using Windows 11 by the way.

[image]

---

**Update: All of the gradient attributes do not work**

Comment: Please try `gradientTransform="rotate(90 0.5 .5)"` where `0.5 0.5` mark the rotation center in the middle

Comment: @enxaneta I tried your suggestion `<linearGradient id="Gradient2" gradientTransform="rotate(90 0.5 .5)">` without success. But thank you for your try, I really thought it will do the trick. My second `rect` is just `blue` and it would have fit to see a portion of the gradient. I will include a screenshot to this question.

Comment: Just a guess: what happens if you use only `gradientTransform` and strip `x1,x2,y1,y2` ? [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/poKXBKN)

Comment: @herrstrietzel I tried both, since they supposed to do the same. But also thanks for your suggestion. I doubt it has something to do [tag:svg] now, it must be a bug in the tcl implementation or [tag:nanosvg] from which it is built upon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional. The library "svgnano" is used. The rasterizer does not support gradients.

Here is the parent project:

https://github.com/memononen/nanosvg

You may also look to the wiki page with some hints:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/svg

Comment: Thanks for answering. However [TIP 507](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/tip/507.md) seems a bit misleading then. Is there somewhere documented what exactly is and what is not supported ?

Answer (score 2):

As I've commented: use `gradientTransform="rotate(90 0.5 0.5)"` where 0.5 0.5 mark the rotation center in the middle

```html
<svg width="120" height="240" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1" gradientTransform="rotate(90 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="black" stop-opacity="0" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="blue" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect id="rect1" x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15"
      width="100" height="100" fill="url(#Gradient1)"/>
  <rect
    x="10"
    y="120"
    rx="15"
    ry="15"
    width="100"
    height="100"
    fill="url(#Gradient2)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but now it is just red instead of blue and I'm expecting the same gradient but horizontal oriented. I can see that your code works, by clicking on "run snippet". So I figure it has something to do with the my environment [tag:tksvg] or [tag:tcl]. And thanks for implementing the `code snippet` on my question. Now I can clearly see that it's not related to the [tag:svg] side.

Comment: Please try adding `gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"` for the second gradient.

Comment: I tried to use `<linearGradient id="Gradient2" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">` but ended up with the same output.