# Tkinter - Modify fill option when using tksvg

Tags: python, tkinter, svg, tksvg

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74797469/tcl-svg-gradient-transformation-not-working-gradient-silently-ignored), I discovered [tksvg](https://pypi.org/project/tksvg/).

I already know how to display an svg file:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tksvg

window = tk.Tk()
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(file="tests/orb.svg")
label = tk.Label(image=svg_image)
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

and also how to do the same using svg data/string:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tksvg

svg_string = """
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><g stroke-width="1.5px" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></path><line x1="4" y1="20" x2="7" y2="20" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></line><line x1="14" y1="20" x2="21" y2="20" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></line><line x1="6.9" y1="15" x2="13.8" y2="15" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></line><line x1="10.2" y1="6.3" x2="16" y2="20" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></line><polyline points="5 20 11 4 13 4 20 20" stroke="#B8B8B8" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5px"></polyline></g></svg>
"""
window = tk.Tk()
svg_image = tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg_string)
label = tk.Label(image=svg_image)
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

but I'm wondering, how do I modify the fill option of the svg element (based on the svg data).

Only way I thought of was to redraw/delete and create the svg element with a different color used in fill.
Here is my attempt:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tksvg

svg_string = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/></svg>'


def change_color(event):
    global svg_string
    fill_color = "blue" if "red" in svg_string else "red"
    svg_string = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="{}"/></svg>'.format(fill_color)
    canvas.delete(image_store[0])
    svg_store.pop(0)
    svg_store.append(tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg_string))
    image_store[0] = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=svg_store[0])

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=200, height=200)
canvas.pack()

image_store = []
svg_store = []
svg_store.append(tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg_string))
image_store.append(canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=svg_store[0]))

canvas.tag_bind(image_store[0], "<Button-1>", change_color)
window.mainloop()
```

Here I tried to switch the color back and forth, so that when it is blue it becomes red, and when red, it becomes blue. But in this case, the color only seems to change once.

I'm only trying to make a workaround since I don't think this is supported yet (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, as I tried to look at the code, with my best attempt at understanding it at [the official github repository](https://github.com/TkinterEP/python-tksvg)).

How can I do this? either using the above workaround (redraw element) or with a better alternative?

I'm on Windows 10, Python version 3.8.10, Tkinter 8.6.9

Comment: For anybody trying to reproduce this, better check first the [tksvg installation doc](https://pypi.org/project/tksvg/).

Comment: yeah, that's why I linked to the pypi link :) should I mention how to install it? I only did a simple `pip install tksvg` on Windows 10 (through Pycharm) @Memristor

Comment: It didn't worked on my Ubuntu, I don't remember last time I had to do `apt install python...` instead of `pip`.

Comment: ah, my bad. I should have thought of posting how to compile it on Linux. I do have access to Linux but mostly made the example above on Windows10 @Memristor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer of "[acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668)".
Creating a new TkImage is costly and you should just update your old image with the new data. Therefore it makes sense to use `image.configure(data=data_string)`, example below:

```
def change_color(event):
    global svg_string
    fill_color = "blue" if "red" in svg_string else "red"
    svg_string = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="{}"/></svg>'.format(fill_color)
    id_, img = image_store[0], svg_store[0]
    img.configure(data=svg_string)
    canvas.itemconfig(id_, image=img)
```

Comment: Just FYI for people in a similar problem, but using itemconfig isn't entirely needed, as this work without it.

Comment: `img, id_ = image_store[0], svg_store[1]` will raise exception as `svg_store` has only one item.  Also `img` and `id_` should be swapped in the line.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you create a new image item at the same position which covers the previous one and so the mouse click event cannot be triggered because the mouse click is on the new image item which does not have the event binding.

You don't need to create a new image item, just update the current image item instead:

```py
def change_color(event):
    global svg_string
    fill_color = "blue" if "red" in svg_string else "red"
    svg_string = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="{}"/></svg>'.format(fill_color)
    svg_store.clear()
    svg_store.append(tksvg.SvgImage(data=svg_string))
    # update the current image item instead of creating a new one
    canvas.itemconfig(image_store[0], image=svg_store[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you want but if you substitute your:

```
canvas.tag_bind(image_store[0], "<Button-1>", change_color)
```

for:

```
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", change_color)
```

the dot changes color. My guess is that when you change the color the image is re-rendered and it becomes another object, so no callback bind to it.

Comment: ah, a silly mistake on my end, thank you.